# Compiler inconsistent accessibility error with passing nested class as a function parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

My visual studio 2010 finds  inconsistent accessibility of parameter type error when I compile this C# code:

```
class Program
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        public class NestedClass
        {

        }
    }

    public static bool Function1(BaseClass.NestedClass obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Function1(new BaseClass.NestedClass());
        new BaseClass.NestedClass();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

but when I comment function1 it works.

```
class Program
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        public class NestedClass
        {

        }
    }

    //public static bool Function1(BaseClass.NestedClass obj)
    //{
    //    return true;
    //}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Function1(new BaseClass.NestedClass());
        new BaseClass.NestedClass();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Why NestedClass can be created but can't be parameter?

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't quite precise with my question. Above I tried to recreate problem in Console application, but in my project I have other structure of classes:

```
         class BaseClass
            {
               public class NestedClass
                {

                }
            }

    public class OtherClass
    {
          public void Function1(BaseClass.NestedClass param)    
                {
                  var newObj = new BaseClass.NestedClass();
                }
    }
```

PS: Setting BaseClass to public really solved my problem. Now, thanks to answers and comments, I understand that it's because public Function1 has greater accessibility than internal (by default) BaseClass. But I don't understand why I can create new NestedClass objects without error?

Comment: The `BaseClass` is by default `private`. The `NestedClass` is not accessible outside of `BaseClass` because `BaseClass` is private. Change `BaseClass` to `public`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top-level types default to being internal, but nested types default to being private. You've therefore got an internal type with a public method that has a private type as a parameter. Making all the access modifiers explicit:

```
internal class Program
{
    private class BaseClass
    {
        public class NestedClass {}
    }

    public static bool Function1(BaseClass.NestedClass obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Function1(new BaseClass.NestedClass());
        new BaseClass.NestedClass();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

That means any code in the rest of the assembly could "see" `Function1` but not understand it - hence the inconsistent accessibility error.

You can fix this by *either* making `BaseClass` internal or public *or* by making `Function1` private. Note that `BaseClass` doesn't have to be public just because `Function1` is public, because the *accessibility domain* of `Program` is just the assembly containing it. That makes the accessibility domain of `Function1` the same. See section 3.5.2 of the C# spec for more details.

Personally I would avoid using nested classes too heavily - and by the time you have a nested type within a nested type, I would *strongly* consider a redesign.

Comment: Thanks! Actually? I just tried to put this question into Console Application from my project and don't have nested type inside nested type. I just thought it was weird that i can create new object of nested type class and cannot pass it as parameter

Comment: @user2893207: I'm confused - you definitely *have* got a doubly-nested type in your question. Are you saying that's not in your real code? It makes it very difficult to discuss things when there are two sets of code to talk about.

Comment: Sorry, I editted question now. When i encountered that problem in project I tried to recreate it in console application and then published.

Answer (score 1):

They have different access levels. You have to declare your BaseClass public or internal.

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        public class NestedClass
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be public. It could be internal. It just has to have at least as large an accessibility domain as the method that refers to it.