# Inconsistent accessibility when using enum as parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, enums

So I'm making a small problem, but ran into a problem. I'm trying to open a (WPF) form using an enum as parameter, as you can see in the code snippet below.

```
public myForm(otherClass.myEnum en)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //my other code comes here
}
```

And in otherClass:

```
class otherClass
{
    public enum myEnum
    {
        item1,
        item2
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that Visual Studio is giving me the following error:

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'myProject.otherClass.myEnum' is less accessible than method 'myProject.myForm.myForm(myProject.otherClass.myEnum)'  C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\myForm.xaml.cs    46  16  myForm
```

However, the enum is public. I looked up the error, but other people usually forgot to make their enum, and I did make mine public. I also prefer not to move the enum to my form class.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: The containing class is not `public` which restricts the visibility of the enum to that of `otherClass`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiler inconsistent accessibility error with passing nested class as a function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442436/compiler-inconsistent-accessibility-error-with-passing-nested-class-as-a-functio)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not knowing this. I don't have that much experience with programming, and didn't think i would have to make a class public. And isn't a nested class a class inside a class? I don't have that so i don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: You have an enum inside a class. The same concept applies to a class inside a class. Learning how to abstract a problem from a specific situation and applying it to your own is what will turn you into a good programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessibility of a type is restricted by it's most outer scoping type accessibility, in our case for the enum it will be the internal because it's scoped inside the definition of the other class and classes by default are defined as internal.
The issue might arise if your form is defined as public and one of it's public members , in our example the public constructor accepts an internal accessibility type argument. 
To fix the issue you can define the other class as public.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `enum` outside of the `class` as `public`, like this:

```
public myForm(otherClass.myEnum en)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //my other code comes here
}
```

```
namespace NameSpace
{
    public enum myEnum
    {
        item1,
        item2
    }

    class otherClass
    {

    }
}
```